# LLVM lib clang CMakeList

Tags: cmake, llvm, llvm-clang

So I am looking at LLVM, specifically at the CMakeLists.txt in /clang/lib. In it there are 2 interesting parts:

```
if(CLANG_ENABLE_ARCMT)
  add_subdirectory(ARCMigrate)
endif()
```

and

```
if(CLANG_ENABLE_STATIC_ANALYZER)
  add_subdirectory(StaticAnalyzer)
endif()
```

What are these 2 directories importance? And how could I potentially remove them from the build?

Comment: Put a meaningful title on your question, not your Google Search.

Comment: OP, have you tried looking into the `CMakeLists.txt` present in both directories?  And if you want to remove them from the build then just find out where and how `CLANG_ENABLE_ARCMT` and `CLANG_ENABLE_STATIC_ANALYZER` are being set and just set your config to omit them.